# How do corpse spiders interact with on-hit properties

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

How does the corpse spiders skill (witch doctor) interact with on-hit properties of gear.

Is there some reduction? Does it proc at all? What about on-hit properties with chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a life per hit property, only the jar hit will give you life, and only at 16% of the listed amount of life.

You may find this link illuminating: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271499223

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.